# plpgsql jsonb_set for JSON array of objects with nested arrays

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Using PostgreSQL 14.0 PL/SQL (inside a *do* block). Attempting to:

1. query a certain key ('county') in a jsonb array of objects (which in turn has object + nested arrays) based on dynamic variable value (named `cty.cty_name`)
2. retrieve value and change it
3. update said jsonb to reflect the updated value in (2)
4. after executing (3) on multiple values, create new table with above jsonb as a row with one column

steps (1) and (2) execute properly. But, for the life of me, I can't figure (3) out.

jsonb object(`res`) -- *may have 100s of array items at index root*:

```
[ {"county": "x", "dpa": ["a", "b", "c"]},
 {"county": "y", "dpa": ["d", "e", "f"]},
 {"county": "z", "dpa": ["h", "i", "j"]},
 ...
]
```

code for (1) and (2) above:

```
execute format('select jsonb_path_query_array(''%s'', ''$[*]?(@.%s=="%s")'')',
            res,'county',cty.cty_name) into s1;
execute format('select jsonb_array_elements(''%s'')->''%s''', s1,'dpa') into s2;
s2 := s2 || jsonb_build_array(r1.name);
```

where say:

- `cty.cty_name` is `y` (which is created from a `select` in `for loop`)
- `r1.name` is `m`

`s2` holds the new value e.g. `["d", "e", "f", "m"]`

Now, to execute (3) I need `path` to `dpa` for which key `county` matches value `y` in some index in `res`. Having tried (and failed miserably) at various permutations of `jsonb_query_path` with SQL/JSON Path, dollar-quoted strings, `jsonb_path_to_array` with double-quoted hell for `format` queries, other SO solutions which use `idx` or `idx-1` (but I don't have JSON in table), I had to resort to soliciting the Borg collective's wisdom. Help please.

Comment: You won't want to hear this, but [don't use JSON for that](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/json-postgresql-how-to-use-it-right/).

Comment: haha.. @LaurenzAlbe I despise JSON. However, the output is supposed to be an input to an interwebs front-end; which meant JSON was the easiest design choice.

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into with the current approach is twofold:

- there's no way to "delete" the matching county object in vitro (via jsonb_set(), etc.)
- there's no way to force uniqueness (to utilize the ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE mechanism) within the json document itself to accomplish the same

When we get to

> Now, to execute (3) I need path to dpa for which key county matches value y in some index in res.

instead of updating the existing record in-place, why not just remove the matching record (with now-stale value for "dpa"), re-aggregate what remains (i.e. the non-matching objects), and then append the updated matching object to the aggregated jsonb array, similar to:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(a) || jsonb_build_object('county', 'y', 'dpa', (jsonb_path_query_array(res, '$[*] ? (@.county=="y")')#>'{0,dpa}') || jsonb_build_array('m') )
FROM jsonb_array_elements(res) a
WHERE NOT a @> (jsonb_path_query_array(res, '$[*] ? (@.county=="y")')->0);
```

This gives a single jsonb value back per your specification in (4); you should be able to parameterize this into your EXECUTE invocation as necessary.

Worth noting on the output order, if you're looping over the initial "res" array, then the order of the objects within the array (with respect to the "county" values of the driving cursor) will be restored according to the order of the cursor you're iterating through for "county".

This is because a full cycle through said cursor will remove each of the old objects and replace them at the end of the resultant array, so defining an ORDER BY clause in this cursor will be important if this is relevant.

Comment: truely appreciate the thoughtful and thorough response. I'll review and implement the recommended changes and report back the results upon return over the next few days (still refusing to start 2022) :-)